# how to reduce opacity to sides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a navigation gallery I'm working on using [sly](https://github.com/darsain/sly) and I need to reduce the opacity of the items from the center to the sides of the screen, but I don't know how to approach it, **something like this**: [image: items with opacity reduced]
Also as you see on the snippet, setting "itemNav: 'forceCentered'", for some reason it separates the start and end of the frames too much from the sides of the window when scrolling, it supposed to look like this when scrolling 'till the sides: [code snippet](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oBdXYr), as you can see the items bounces to the sides.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  'use strict';

  // -------------------------------------------------------------
  //   Basic Navigation
  // -------------------------------------------------------------
  (function() {
    var $frame = $('#basic');
    var $slidee = $frame.children('ul').eq(0);
    var $wrap = $frame.parent();

    // Call Sly on frame
    $frame.sly({
      horizontal: 1,
      itemNav: 'forceCentered',
      smart: 1,
      activateMiddle: true,
      activateOn: 'click',
      mouseDragging: 1,
      touchDragging: 1,
      releaseSwing: 1,
      startAt: 3,
      scrollBar: $wrap.find('.scrollbar'),
      scrollBy: 1,
      pagesBar: $wrap.find('.pages'),
      activatePageOn: 'click',
      speed: 300,
      elasticBounds: 1,
      easing: 'easeOutExpo',
      dragHandle: 1,
      dynamicHandle: 1,
      clickBar: 1
    });
  }());
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
 }
.frame {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.clearfix {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
li {
  float: left;
  width: 227px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 1px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #333;
  color: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.7;
  font-size: 50px;
}
li.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="frame" id="basic">
    <ul class="clearfix">
      <li>0</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://darsa.in/sly/examples/js/vendor/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Sly/1.6.1/sly.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `active` event.

Loop all child and add class to apply opacity style.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  'use strict';

  // -------------------------------------------------------------
  //   Basic Navigation
  // -------------------------------------------------------------
  (function() {
    var $frame = $('#basic');
    var $slidee = $frame.children('ul').eq(0);
    var $wrap = $frame.parent();

    // Call Sly on frame
    $frame.sly({
      horizontal: 1,
      itemNav: 'forceCentered',
      smart: 1,
      activateMiddle: true,
      activateOn: 'click',
      mouseDragging: 1,
      touchDragging: 1,
      releaseSwing: 1,
      startAt: 3,
      scrollBar: $wrap.find('.scrollbar'),
      scrollBy: 1,
      pagesBar: $wrap.find('.pages'),
      activatePageOn: 'click',
      speed: 300,
      elasticBounds: 1,
      easing: 'easeOutExpo',
      dragHandle: 1,
      dynamicHandle: 1,
      clickBar: 1
    });

    $frame.sly('on', 'active', active);
    active(null, 3);
    
    function active(e, idx) {
      $("#ul").find('li').removeClass();
      $("#ul").find('li').each(function(i, elem) {
        setOpacityClass(Math.abs(i - idx), elem);
        if (i == idx) {
          $(elem).addClass('active');
        }
      })
    }

    function setOpacityClass(grad, elem) {
      $(elem).addClass('op-' + grad);
    }

  }());
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
}
.frame {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.clearfix {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
li {
  float: left;
  width: 227px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 1px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #333;
  color: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.7;
  font-size: 50px;
}

li.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

li.op-0 {
  opacity: 1;
}
li.op-1 {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
li.op-2 {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
li.op-3 {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
li.op-4 {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
li.op-5 {
  opacity: 0.1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="frame" id="basic">
    <ul id="ul" class="clearfix">
      <li>0</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://darsa.in/sly/examples/js/vendor/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Sly/1.6.1/sly.min.js"></script>
```